# nodejs mysql module errors

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a nodejs module which get result from a mysql database and insert into another mysql database within a given interval. After few queries it just get stuck and throw "ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR" and says Too many connections. My module is as follows:

```
function get_data() {
const mysql = require('mysql');
const moment = require('moment');

var items_per_query = 1000;
let to_connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'username',
    password: 'pass',
    database: 'todatabase'
});

let from_connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'username',
    password: 'pass',
    database: 'fromdatabase'
});


from_connection.query("SELECT p.*, d.uniqueid as imei FROM tc_positions p left join tc_devices d on d.id = p.deviceid order by p.id desc limit " + items_per_query, function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var items = [];
    var table_columns_list = {};
    if (Object.keys(result).length > 0) {
        Object.keys(result).forEach(function (key) {
            var x = result[key];
            table_columns_list = {
                'dt_server': moment(x['servertime']).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss'),
                'dt_tracker': moment(x['devicetime']).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss'),
                'lat': x['latitude'],
                'long': x['longitude'],
                'altitude': x['altitude'],
                'angle': x['course'],
                'speed': x['speed'],
                'params': x['attributes'],
                'fix_time': moment(x['fixtime']).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss'),
                'accuracy': x['accuracy'],
                'network': x['network']
            }
            items.push({ 'id': x['id'], 'table_name': 'table_' + x['imei'], 'table_columns': table_columns_list });
        });
    }

    if (items.length >=500) {
        var items_to_be_removed = [];
        var total_rows_inserted = 0;
        for (var x = 0; x < items.length; x++) {
           
            to_connection.query(imei_insert, function (err, results, fields) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err.message);
                }
                else {
                    let createTable = " create table if not exists .... ";

                    to_connection.query(createTable, function (err, results, fields) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err.message);
                        }
                        else {
                            let insert_data = "INSERT INTO .... ";

                            to_connection.query(insert_data, function (err, results, fields) {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log(err.message);
                                }
                                total_rows_inserted++;
                                items_to_be_removed.push(row_id);

                                if (total_rows_inserted == items.length) {
                                    //remove data from traccar positions table that were inserted to platform
                                    var ids = items_to_be_removed.join(",");
                                    from_connection.query("DELETE FROM tc_positions where id IN(" + ids + ")", function (err, results, fields) {
                                        if (err) throw err;
                                        console.log('removed ' + total_rows_inserted + ' rows from traccar');
                                        return get_data(); // after finish all task call the same function again
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    });
                }

            });
        }
    }
    else {
        setInterval(get_data, 15000);
    }
});
```

}
and I just  call get_data(); function to run. Is there any efficient way to run this module smoothly. I should run it 7 days 24 hours without any interruption.

Comment: Firstly, I suggest you use [mysql.createPool](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections) to handle backend connection from nodejs. Then check you `max_connections` variable setting; [refer here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/too-many-connections.html) for more info

Comment: hello... thanks for your suggestion... now i use connection pool for database query. But i m passing the pool configuration as parameter to get_data function. it works for few queries.. then just stop... but i want it to run infinitely

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new connection to the servers each time `get_data()` runs, which is overwhelming them.  You need to reuse connections, as for example with [connection pooling](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections).